# Using dovecot for submission, how to configure dkim?

Tags: dovecot, dkim

All the tutorials that I've found regarding this issue always focus on postfix. But I'm using dovecot as the submission server. I'm under the impression that it does not use postfix to send emails. So I'm wondering how I can configure DKIM with dovecot.

Comment: Dovecot does IMAP and POP3, not SMTP. It does offer a [smtp proxy](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Submission) which is a recent feature but would still rely on an actual MTA so send the mail.

Comment: Ah so the submission service is just a proxy to the smtp server (in this case postfix). Therefore I still should configure DKIM with postfix

Comment: you should put your comment as the answer, so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dovecot does IMAP and POP3, not SMTP. It does offer a [smtp proxy](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Submission) which is a recent feature but would still rely on an actual MTA so send the mail.